# MFMessageComposeViewController: Cannot Style "Cancel" Button in Dark Mode

Tags: objective-c, ios-darkmode, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I'm currently trying to style the "cancel" button that is in the top right corner (the navigation bar and the button are both grey) and I am having no luck. I've tried calling several different methods and none have worked. My project builds for iOS12.1 and I'm testing via iOS15.4. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                          [UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura-Medium" size:17.0f],
                                                          NSFontAttributeName,
                                                          [UIColor blueColor],
                                                          NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                          nil]];
```

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *messageController;
[messageController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
messageController = [MFMessageComposeViewController new];
```

```
[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[UINavigationBar class]]].tintColor = [UIColor RepublicBrightBlue];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gray color for the button is likely coming from the global tint color for your application. This is by default AccentColor that comes within Assets (this is mapped via Build Settings). Note that you can define separate global accent colors for `Any, Light, Dark`
[image]

If you're just interested in styling this MFMessageComposeViewController the following worked for me to change the tint color for all views within the message view:

```objectivec
MFMessageComposeViewController *messageController = [MFMessageComposeViewController new];
[self presentViewController:messageController animated:true completion:nil];
[UIView appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[MFMessageComposeViewController class]]].tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Which results in [image]

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! I ended up using the code solution because I just wanted to change specific message controllers.